# Template class with template container

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

How can I declare template class (adaptor) with different containers as template arguments? 
For example, I need to declare class:

```
template<typename T, typename Container>
class MyMultibyteString
{
    Container buffer;
    ...
};
```

And I want it to my based on vector. How to make it hard-defined? (to prevent someone from writing such declaration `MyMultibyteString<int, vector<char>>`).

Moreover, how to implement such construction:

```
MyMultibyteString<int, std::vector> mbs;
```

without passing template argument to container.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You should use *template template parameters*:

```
template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container>
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MyMultibyteString
{
    Container<T, std::allocator<T>> buffer;
    // ...
};
```

This would allow you to write:

```
MyMultibyteString<int, std::vector> mbs;
```

Here is a compiling [*live example*](http://ideone.com/KCGDNI). An alternative way of writing the above could be:

```
template<typename T,
    template <typename, typename = std::allocator<T>> class Container>
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
class MyMultibyteString
{
    Container<T> buffer; // <== No more need to specify the second argument here
    // ...
};
```

And here is the corresponding [*live example*](http://ideone.com/FCNF75).

The only thing you have to pay attention to is that the number and type of arguments in the template template parameter declaration must match exactly the number and type of arguments in the definition of the corresponding class template you want to pass as a template argument, regardless of the fact that some of those parameters may have default values.

For instance, [the class template `std::vector` accepts two template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (the element type and the allocator type), although the second one has the default value `std::allocator<T>`. Because of this, you could *not* write:

```
template<typename T, template <typename> class Container>
//                             ^^^^^^^^
//                             Notice: just one template parameter declared!
class MyMultibyteString
{
    Container<T> buffer;
    // ...
};

// ...

MyMultibyteString<int, std::vector> mbs; // ERROR!
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                     The std::vector class template accepts *two*
//                     template parameters (even though the second
//                     one has a default argument)
```

This means that you won't be able to write one single class template that can accept both `std::set` and `std::vector` as a template template parameter, because unlike `std::vector`, [the `std::set` class template accepts *three* template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: What a great, thorough answer.

Comment: @ScottJones: Glad you found it useful :)

Comment: @ScottJones Regarding your statement: `This means that you won't be able to write one single class template that can accept both std::set and std::vector`: Would variadic templates solve the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20499809/2436175

Comment: @Antonio: Yep, that's a possibility. Not sure why I haven't thought of that :)

Comment: "This means that you won't be able to write one single class template that can accept both `std::set` and `std::vector`...because `std::set` accepts three template parameters" - What about variadic templates? `template< class... Args >`

Answer (score 12):

Another approach to solve this is by using variadic templates and with that you can use any container as suggested in comments above and here is the implemenation :

```
template<template <typename... Args> class Container,typename... Types>
class Test
{
    public:
    Container<Types...> test;

};
int main()
{
  Test<std::vector,int> t;
  Test<std::set,std::string> p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: and how would a function look like that return a `Container<Types...>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definitions of **list** and ***vector*** from *cplusplus.com*, for example they are:

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class list;
```

and

```
template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> > class vector;
```

So this should go as the type of the container, the other template parameter is the type of the elements. As an example this program will output *3*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <template <typename...> typename C, typename T>
struct Cont {
    C<T> info;
};
int main(void)
{
    Cont<list, int> cont;

    cont.info.push_back(3);
    cout << cont.info.front() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```