# template template parameters with container and default allocator: can I make my declaration more compact?

Tags: c++, templates, opencv

I was looking at this interesting thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16596463/2436175

My specific case concerns declaring a templated function using a std container of cv::Point_ and cv::Rect_ from opencv.
I want to template against:

- the type of std container I will use
- the basic data types to complete the definition of cv::Point_ and cv::Rect_

I ended up with the following declaration:

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container_t>
    void CreateRects(const Container_t<cv::Point_<T>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<T> > >& points,
                     const T value,
                     Container_t<cv::Rect_<T>,std::allocator<cv::Rect_<T> > >& rects) {

    }
```

which compiles fine with this:

```
void dummy() {

const std::vector<cv::Point_<double> > points;
std::vector<cv::Rect_<double> > rects;
CreateRects(points,5.0,rects);

}
```

(I have also seen that I can also use, for example, `CreateRects<double>(points,5,rects)`)

I was wondering if there existed any way to make my declaration more compact, e.g. without the need to specify 2 times the default allocator.

Comment: Why do you want to compact the declaration?  There is no performance gain and the accumulated time saved during the build, has been wasted by posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If I could improve could readibility in any way, it might save time to people (even myself) having to deal with my code later. But you do have a point. Sometimes I just ask questions because I found them interesting, and not necessarily immediately useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add description for template parameters of template template parameter `Container_t` to your function template:

```
template
    <
        typename T,
        template
            <
                typename U,
                typename = std::allocator<U>
            >
        class Container_t
    >
void CreateRects
    (
        const Container_t<cv::Point_<T> >& points,
        const T value,
        Container_t<cv::Rect_<T> >& rects
    )
{

}
```

Or you can use C++11 variadic templates:

```
template
    <
        typename T,
        template <typename...> class Container_t
    >
void CreateRects
    (
        const Container_t<cv::Point_<T>>& points,
        const T value,
        Container_t<cv::Rect_<T>>& rects
    )
{

}
```

Comment: Good stuff, thank you! Actually, I now realize that the answer to my question was already in the link I posted, I wonder how I missed that! Your answer adds the variadic templates to the picture, so after all I am glad I asked :)

Comment: @Antonio There is a small difference between `template <typename T, template <typename U, typename = std::allocator<U> > class Container_t> void CreateRects(...);` and `template <typename T, template <typename, typename = std::allocator<T> > class Container_t> void CreateRects(...);`. But you are right, the similar solution was in your link.

Answer (score 0):

What's about going with simple code like:

```
template <typename T, class C1, class C2>
void CreateRects(const C1& points,
                 const T value,
                 C2& rects) {

}
```

It's easier to read, compiles, and if types are mismatched, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: The 2 container contain 2 different type of objects (Point_<T> and Rect_<T>), are you sure this works? Trying, quite expectedly I get a `template argument deduction/substitution failed` error, `deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Container_t' (std::vector<cv::Point_<double> > and std::vector<cv::Rect_<double> >`

Comment: Didn't notice you're using 2 containers. I'll fix this... Fixed

Comment: Hmmmm... I undestand this works, but I would like to have a little bit more control, e.g. I would like to force that the 2 containers are of the same kind (both vectors, or both lists)