# How to create a template class with a template container of different objects as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates, vector, template-templates

How can i declare a template class (A library of components) which will take a vector containing the components as a parameter?
Here is a stripped down version of code as an example:

```
    // In Library.h
    using namespace std;

    template<typename T,
        template <typename, typename = std:allocator<T>> class Container>
    class library {
        Container<T> comp_lib;
        library(Container<T> &Vc) {comp_lib = Vc}
    };

    // In mainProgram.cpp
    #include "Library.h"
    // Other includes...
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
    library<int, vector> intLib;
    return(0);
    }
```

As I mentioned before this is meant to be a library of components. So instead of holding vectors containing integers the library template is meant to hold vectors containing general components, vectors containing resistors, vectors containing capacitors and vectors containing inductors. Where resistors, capacitors and inductors are all derived classes from the component base class.

When I run the code, it does not compile and I receive these error messages:

C2079: 'intLib' uses undefined class 'library'  on line [ library intLib ] in mainProgram.cpp

C3855 'library': template parameter 'C' is incompatible with the declaration
on line [ }; ] in library.h (The last line)

C3855 'library': template parameter 'vector' is incompatible with the declaration on line [ }; ] in library.h (also, the last line)

I've looked at lots of different articles concerning template template parameters, this answer has been especially useful so far although it doesn't seem to solve the problem I'm currently having:
[Template class with template container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596422/template-class-with-template-container?answertab=active#tab-top)

The desired result is to be able to write a statements such as:

```
      library<resistor, vector<resistor>> resistor_lib;
      library<capacitor, vector<capacitor>> capacitor_lib;
      library<inductor, vector<inductor>> inductor_lib;
      library<component, vector<component>> component_lib;
```

in the main all using the same template.

Thanks, any help is much appreciated

Comment: You don't have default constructor, nor you have a public constructor at all.

Comment: Yeah, apologies, forgot to add the constructor to the example. This is just a much stripped down bit of code attempting to illustrate the problem without being too convoluted. The original code does have public default and parameterised constructors and still doesn't compile

Answer (score 1):

You only need to template the the container and then let it tell the stored type. The standard containers do that by means of the `value_type`  definition. Do something like:

```
template <typename TContainer>
class Library {
private:

    TContainer container_;

public:

    using container_type = TContainer;
    using value_type = typename TContainer::value_type;

    Library(const container_type &initValues) {
        std::copy(initValues.begin(), initValues.end(),
            std::back_inserter(container_));
    }

    [...]
};
```

This should work with `vector`, `list` and everything that can be "back_inserted". Additionally you can reference the container and object types by means of `container_type` and `value_type`.

Instances are declared like

```
Library<std::vector<int> > lib(someInitializer);
```

Comment: std containers are copy-constructible. you can copy-initialise container_ in the Library's constructor initialisation list