# Making a template class with template containers

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, containers, c++17

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596422/template-class-with-template-container), I wrote down:

`template <typename T, template <T> typename C>
class Base`

Base class contains a '`C`' type container that contains '`T`' type objects.

My problem is when I try to make a derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
```

The first error was

> argument list for class template is missing.

So I figured I have to tell the template `Base` class what types I'm gonna use. So suppose my derived class will have a '`std::set`' for container that has integers.

```
class Derived : public Base <int, set<int>>
```

But it '`std::set<int>`' gets underlined in red and it tells me it's "not a template class".

I'm not sure to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your either need to qualify your template template class correctly, or provide a variadic solution (which is doable). Either will work.

Comment: What your IDE marks as an error is far less important then actual compile errors. Post the full compiler error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> template  typename C>
>   class Base
>
> Base class contains a 'C' type container that contains 'T' type objects.

Not in the sense that `C` is a container like `std::set`. I mean: `C` doesn't receive a template type parameter as STL containers.

With your `Base` you can write

```
template <int>
struct foo
 { };

template <typename T, template <T> typename C>
class Base
 { };

class Derived : public Base <int, foo>
 { };
```

where `foo` receive a integer, not a type.

If you want a `std::set` as second parameter, you can write

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> typename C>
class Base
 { };
```

where `C` receive a variadic list of types (`std::set` receive **three** template type parameters; the second and the third are defaulted).

So you can write

```
class Derived : public Base <int, std::set>
 { };
```

Another way is write `Base` as receiving a single type and use partial specialization to resolve container and container template paramenter

```
template <typename>
class Base;

template <template <typename...> typename C, typename A0, typename ... As>
class Base<C<A0, As...>>
 { };
```

so you can pass directly the type `std::set<int>` (with defaulted template types) as follows

```
class Derived : public Base <std::set<int>>
 { };
```